# How do I view an object in Lightning when I only have its ID?

Tags: lightning

It has been a while since I last worked in Salesforce. In the old days I could just append an object Id like `a0u0Y00001Jt0khQAB` to the page url and I could view it. If all I have is an object's id, how do I navigate to view the object in Lightning? I tried entering the number in the search box, but nothing was found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It still works in lightning as well. Just append your Id after force.com site ex.

```
https://testdev.lightning.force.com/0060J00000tod44QAA
```

it will automatically take you to

```
https://testdev.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0060J00000tod44QAA/view
```

try yourself

**Note**: If you are in classic just move to lightning by click on **switch to lightning Experience** link and try this method. If you are in lightning it will goto lightning or it will go to the classic detail page.

Comment: Perfect! I should have tried that, but my expectations were not high enough, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The record view url format for Lightning Expereince is as below.

```
https://<lightning.domain.com>/one/one.app#/sObject/<recordID>/view
```

If your Salesforce org has the new url format enabled for your org the Record View url becomes

```
https://<lightning.domain.com>/lightning/r/<ObjectAPIName>/<recordID>/view
```

> For example:
>   `https://lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Invoice__c/a0U90000008tQF4EAM/view`

Refer the [New Lightning URL Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/heres-need-know-new-url-format-lightning.html) article to understand more on how this works.

Comment: I believe `/lightning/r/<recordId>/view` works too. It redirects to the URL that includes the object name.